# javascript change color of a dynamically added row

Tags: javascript, hta

I been doing a small script in HTA in which it reads info from text files and show the info on screen.
I have a table with a header row.

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" id="TablaResultados" style="font-size:10;">
  <tr bgcolor="#cd0041" align="center" style="color:white;">
    <th>Fecha</th>
    <th>Id Evento</th>
    <th>Tipo Evento</th>
    <th>Ubicacion</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Comentarios</th>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in this table I add dynamically rows of the info I read using javascript

```
function AgregarFila(Datos) {
  var table = document.getElementById("TablaResultados");
  var ArrDatos = Datos.split("@");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var LargoArreglo = ArrDatos.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < LargoArreglo; i++){
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(i);
    cell1.innerHTML = ArrDatos[i];
    cell1.style.backgroundColor = "#99cc00"; 
  }
}
```

every N rows I need to clear the color of the rows to white, and I am using this

```
function TablaABlanco() {
  var table = document.getElementById("TablaResultados");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
  }
}
```

My issue is that it does not change the color of the rows. I know that the function `TablaABlanco` does work because if I run the `for loop` from zero it changes the color of the header of the previous table.

I believe I might need to check something else to validate the new rows but I have been googling with no luck.

Comment: Where function TablaABlanco is called?

Comment: before adding a row with "AgregarFila"

Comment: @CesarLopez So your problem is that TablaABlanco isn't turning the new rows white?

Comment: thats correct.. if i add static rows in the previous table it does change those rows but the ones added by "AgregarFila" it does not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in `AgregarFila`, you set the each **cell** to have a background color. In `TablaABlanco`, you set the **row** to be white. The style on the cell will take priority and override the style you apply to the row.

So instead of changing each cell to have the background color, you change the row's background color when you add it.

```
function AgregarFila(Datos) {
    var table = document.getElementById("TablaResultados");
    var ArrDatos = Datos.split("@");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    row.style.backgroundColor = "#99cc00";

    var LargoArreglo = ArrDatos.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < LargoArreglo; i++){
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(i);
        cell1.innerHTML = ArrDatos[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: That do the trick!Did not know that the cell had priority on the row

Comment: @CesarLopez No problem. I would very much appreciate it if you can mark this answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.